# Convert a decimal.Decimal to a string with a fixed number of characters

Tags: python, string, floating-point, string-formatting

Surprisingly, I can't seem to find this particular question answered previously, although it seems like something that would be pretty standard.

I want to be able to, given a length *L*, convert any positive Decimal between 1E-100 and 1E+100 (non-inclusive) to a string with exactly *L* characters.  I would like to:

- Preserve as many digits of precision as possible
- Avoid adding any extra zeroes (which would misrepresent the precision)
- Avoid a leading or trailing decimal point (e.g. ".1" or "1.")
- Only resort to scientific notation if necessary

Here's some examples, where *L* is 10:

| Decimal Value | String |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0000100 | `0.0000100` |
| 0.00001000 | `0.00001000` |
| 0.000010000 | `1.0000E-05` |
| 0.123456789 | `0.12345679` |
| 10 | `10` |
| 1E+01 | `1E+01` |
| 100000000 | `100000000` |
| 100000000.0 | `100000000` |
| 10000000.0 | `10000000.0` |
| 10000000000 | `1.0000E+10` |

The most concise way I can think of doing this is:

```
# x is Decimal, L is length of return string

def posDecimalToString(x, L):
    nDigits = significantDigits(x)
    stdStr = str(x)
    stdLen = len(str(x))

    if (x >= 10 ** L) or (x >= 10 ** nDigits) or (stdLen - L > nDigits - (L - charsUsedByScientific(x))):
        rStr = decimalToScientific(x, L)

    else:
        rStr = stdStr[:10]
        if(rStr[-1:] == "."): rStr = rStr[:-1]
    
    return (" " * (L - len(rStr))) + rStr
        
def decimalToScientific(x, L):
    if significantDigits(x) > (L - charsUsedByScientific(x)):
        return '{:.' + str((L - charsUsedByScientific(x)) - 1) + 'E}'.format(x)
    else:
        return '{:E}'.format(x)

def charsUsedByScientific(x):
    sciStr = '{:E}'.format(x)
    return len(sciStr) - len(sciStr[:sciStr.find('E')])

def significantDigits(x):
    return len(x.as_tuple().digits)
```

But this just seems far too long-winded for Python. I would think a problem as commonplace as formatting a number with precision would have an implementation in some library.  Is there a more concise way to do it?

Comment: If you haven't found a library for it (I haven't either), this looks like a good foundation for one :)

Comment: Why does `"0.000010000"` format as scientific, wouldn't `".000010000"` meet the requirements with length 10?

Comment: I don't want a leading or trailing decimal point.  Sorry, I will edit the post to clarify that.